# Is there a way to change letter spacing (tracking) in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, nsattributedstring

There are two different types of letter spacing: Kerning and Tracking. 
Kerning can be changed using `NSAttributedStringKey.kern`

Can tracking also be changed?

Answer (score 0):

[`.expansion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1524652-expansion):

> The value of this attribute is an `NSNumber` object containing a floating point value indicating the log of the expansion factor to be applied to glyphs. The default value is 0, indicating no expansion.

Comment: Are you sure this is the value for tracking? By default, UILabels have > 0 tracking (you can tell because letters aren't touching each other)

Comment: Well, it may not correspond directly to tracking in the sense of having the same origin. But it's how you expand or compress the distance between characters. Note that it's the **log** of the expansion factor, so a value of 0 means the expansion factor is 1 (basically, normal distance * 1). If you make the value positive, the expansion factor will be >1 and the distance will increase; if you make it negative, the expansion factor will be a fraction between 0 and 1 and the distance will decrease.

Comment: If you want complete control, you can use Core Text and Core Graphics to get glyphs and, if you want, the normal advances/positions; generate alternative advances/positions however you like (based on the normal ones or not); and draw the glyphs with your advances/positions.

Comment: Good to know about the log. Where did you find out about this? I'd like to read more.

Comment: Where'd I learn about what? About the attribute key? That's just in the docs I've linked. So is the fact that it uses the log of the expansion factor. As to the behavior of [logarithms](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/logarithms.html), well, that's just math. I learned about it in school. :)

Comment: :) Where did you learn that the `.expansion` is the log of the expansion factor?

Comment:  Can't believe I didn't see that.

After testing `.expansion` in UILabel, it doesn't seem to actually be the tracking value. It expands the letter width, not the spacing between the letters.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry about that. Maybe you can achieve this with a modified font. I see that `UIFontDescriptor` supports an attribute `.fixedAdvance`, if you're looking for a fixed advance. There's also `traits`, the value for which is a dictionary one of whose keys can be `width`.